# Unable to fetch JSON fromlocal host with retrofit in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to fetch JSON from localhost but unable to do so.
I can access the file by typing the URL (http://10.0.2.2/evapo/json_get_data.php) in browser of virtual device but somehow am not able to access it from within code.

Main Activity Class

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    private val CROP_BASE_URL="http://10.0.2.2/"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        makeAPIRequest()
    }

    fun makeAPIRequest()
    {
        val api:APIRequest =Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(APIRequest::class.java)

            GlobalScope.launch {
                try {
                    Log.d("TEST", "makeAPIRequest: HERE")
                    val response:ServerResponse=api.getCropData()

                     //control never reach here
                    Log.d("TEST", "makeAPIRequest:"+response)


                }catch (e:Exception)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

API Request Interface

```
interface APIRequest {

   @GET("evapo/json_get_data.php")
    suspend fun getCropData():ServerResponse

}
```

Crop Response Class

```
data class CropResponse(
    @SerializedName("server_response")
    val serverResponse: List<ServerResponse>
)
```

Server Response Class

```
data class ServerResponse(
    @SerializedName("cropName")
    val cropName: String,
    @SerializedName("eigth_month")
    val eigthMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("eleventh_month")
    val eleventhMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("fifth_month")
    val fifthMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("first_month")
    val firstMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("fourth_month")
    val fourthMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("nineth_month")
    val ninethMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("second_month")
    val secondMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("seventh_month")
    val seventhMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("sixth_month")
    val sixthMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("sowingDate")
    val sowingDate: String,
    @SerializedName("tenth_month")
    val tenthMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("third_month")
    val thirdMonth: String,
    @SerializedName("twelveth_month")
    val twelvethMonth: String
)
```

json_get_data.php returns

```
{
  "server_response": [
    {
      "cropName": "Cotton",
      "sowingDate": "03-03-2020",
      "first_month": "85.59",
      "second_month": "185.134",
      "third_month": "261.88",
      "fourth_month": "388.608",
      "fifth_month": "312.979",
      "sixth_month": "219.848",
      "seventh_month": "193",
      "eigth_month": "0",
      "nineth_month": "0",
      "tenth_month": "0",
      "eleventh_month": "0",
      "twelveth_month": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Log Cat

```
2020-09-01 13:10:06.608 10803-10828/dummy.dummy D/TEST: makeAPIRequest: HERE
```

Linking Stack trace from log cat, because character limit was reached
[Stack trace](https://pastebin.com/dYrnY4VR)

**Solution**

- Changed the return type as specified in accepted answer.
- Was passing a wrong URL instead of "http://10.0.2.2/" to baseURL()

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace from the logcat.

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your API returns a list you need to return

```
suspend fun getCropData(): CropResponse
```

in API Request Interface

Answer (score 0):

Since your api is returning a list, you need to return `CropResponse` wrapped in the `Resonse` object from Retrofit in the `getCropData()` function as follows.

```
interface APIRequest {

   @GET("evapo/json_get_data.php")
    suspend fun getCropData() : Response<CropResponse>

}
```

Then, inside the coroutine you get the data as follows:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    try {
        Log.d("TEST", "makeAPIRequest: HERE")
        val response: CropResponse = api.getCropData().body()
        val serverResponse: List<ServerResponse> = response.serverResponse
    
        Log.d("TEST", "makeAPIRequest:"+response)
    
    }catch (e:Exception)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```